# attribute error during recursive scraping with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider that works well as long as I give it a page that contains the links to the pages that it should scrape.
Now I want to not give it all the categories but the page that contains links to all categories.
I thought I could simply add another parse function in order to achieve this.

but the console output gives me an attribute error

> "attributeError: 'zaubersonder' object has no attribute
> 'parsedetails'"

This tells me that [some attribute reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references) is not working correctly.
I am new to object orientation but I thought scrapy is calling parse which is calling prase_level2 which in turn calls parse_details and this should work fine.

below is my effort so far.

```
import scrapy


class zaubersonder(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zaubersonder'
    allowed_domains = ['abc.de']
    start_urls = ['http://www.abc.de/index.php/rgergegregre.html'
                 ]




    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('a.ulSubMenu::attr(href)').extract() # links to categories
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_level2)

    def parse_level2(self, response):
        urls2 = response.css('a.ulSubMenu::attr(href)').extract() # links to entries
        for url2 in urls2:
            url2 = response.urljoin(url2)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url2,callback=self.parse_details)

    def parse_details(self,response): #extract entries
        yield {
            "Titel": response.css("li.active.last::text").extract(),
            "Content": response.css('div.ce_text.first.block').extract() + response.css('div.ce_text.last.block').extract(),
        }
```

**edit**: fixed the code in case someone will search for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the code. The callback in `parse_level2` is `self.parsedetails`, but the function is named `parse_details`.

Just change the `yield` in `parse_level2` to:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=url2,callback=self.parse_details)
```

..and it should work better.